# Tamanho da página igual ao tamanho do IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp, iframe

Como eu faço para que uma página que está sendo executada dentro de um IFrame, tenha exatamente as dimensões do IFrame? Meu IFrame tem 700px X 500px, mas a página que está sendo executada dentro dele ocupa a metade o IFrame ou menos e cria scroll horizontal e vertical. Como eu faço? Já pesquisei na net e só encontro o tamanho do IFrame, mas o da página inserida nele.
A passagem de parâmetors para o IFrame(página). Observe que tem um width=700 e um heigth=500:

```
../../ace/ace005a.asp?/GEN/ASP/GEN0001a.asp$$ind_situacao=&tipo_empresa=&ind_classificacao=&p_cod_tipo_contrato=&indsubmit=false&txt_nome_campo_cod=num_contrato&txt_nome_campo_cod_ts=cod_ts_contrato&txt_nome_campo_desc=nome_contrato&ind_tipo_pessoa=J&funcao_executar=PesquisaContratoMontaFilial();&abre_modal=S&ind_alteracao_contrato=&tipo_preco=", "Pesquisa Contrato", 700, 500
```

Veja como está a página dentro. O Frame é grande, mas a página dentro fica ocupando menos da metade do IFrame.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se você tiver controle da página que está sendo chamada pelo iFrame, você tem que programar ela para se adequar ao tamanho do iFrame.  Tem como acessar elementos que estão dentro de um iFrame, mas não sei se será permitido pelo browser, se for outro domínio...

Answer (score 1):

O conteúdo que vc está inserindo é maior que 700x500, por isso as barras de rolagem...Utilizando um layout responsivo vc resolve o problema da rolagem horizontal. Isso pode ser feito com bootstrap ou foundation, já a barra de rolagem vertical deve existir para garantir que informações não sejam omitidas.

Exemplo utilizando o bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) para escrever uma pagina de formulário:

Formulário

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
        <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
        <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Bem, não é essa a questão. Debugando no browser, pude ver que o IFrame tem as seguintes dimensões: 323.438px X 467.719px. O problema é que o IFrame é que não acompanhou as dimensões do Modal: 700px X 500px. Vou fechar esse post e abrir outro, para saber como eu redimensiono um IFrame dentro de um Modal.

Comment: Como eu fecho essa pergunta para abrir outra? Os opções que me aparecem, não corresponde ao motivo pelo qual desejo fechar. A que mais se aproximou foi, fora de escopo. Não está fora de escopo do site, mas vi pelos meus testes que deveria refazer a pergunta para: Como redimensionar o IFrame para ter as dimensões do Modal. Posso editar essa pergunta e alterar completamente o corpo dela? E a(s) resposta(s) que estão, ficarão sem nenhum sentido. Se eu fizer outra com essa aberta, alguém poderá dizer que é duplicada e aí gera uma série de problemas. O que eu quero é fechar essa e abrir outra.

Comment: Excluir pode ser uma opção, mas a pergunta pode ajudar outros, até porque já possui uma resposta. Não gostaria de excluí-la.

Answer (score 0):

Pode não ser a melhor solução se o conteúdo da sua página for dinâmica e puder ficar maior do que o iframe, mas tenta colocar scrolling="no" pra desabilitar os scrolls no iframe.

E no width e height da página no src do iframe coloca 100% pra que ocupe todo o espaço disponível no iframe.

Comment: O scroll não está no IFrame, mas sim na página dentro do IFrame. Fiz conforme o Int falou e nada. Na internet não acho nada a respeito.

Comment: Tenta colocar 
overflow: hidden

Comment: Então, fiz isso mas no CSS e mesmo assim nada. O que passa, que parece que o meu código não reconhece: type="text/css", isso não funciona e qualquer coisa que eu coloco no css não faz efeito algum. fiz assim: iframe.semScroll{
           width: 700px;
           height: 500px;
           overflow: hidden;
        } e a chamada assim: <iframe id="dialog" class="ui-helper-hidden semScroll"></iframe>

Comment: Creio que esse é o problema. O tamanho que foi criado no método jquery é o dimensionamento do Modal. Logo a pergunta segue um outro rumo. Como dimensionar o IFrame dentro do modal. Acho que o problema está no Modal e não no IFrame.